# JQuery throw if more than an element is returned by a selector

Tags: jquery

In jQuery is there a way to throw/return no elements if jQuery selector returns more than one DOM element? I know you can wrap every call with a simple check, but I'd like to use an existing method if any.

Comment: Are you asking how to check if a selector returns more than one element? In that case you have to use $(selector).lengh.

Comment: Sorry made a typo - I've updated the question, I was wondering if there's an existing JQuery method for doing that, something like $("#blah", trowIfMultipleFound);...

Comment: No, you'd either have to write your own function that checks the length property, extend jQuery, or modify the jQuery source code.

Comment: You want to return an error, or you just want to work on the first element (and discard the rest)?

Comment: I'd have thought it's quite a common source of mistakes and it's been looked after.

Comment: It depends on what you're doing; jQuery can work on single elements, multiple elements or no elements (if no elements are found matching the supplied pattern) without throwing any errors. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: duplicate names which is enforced by Html sometime can cause problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in method, but it wouldn't be hard to add one:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.oneOnly = function() {
        if (this.length === 1) {
            return this;
        } else {
            return $();  // or throw / $.error()
        }
    };
 })(jQuery);
```

Put it in a chain to null out the chain if more than one element matched:

```
 $(sel).oneOnly().doSomething();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/sevTY/

Comment: @Alnitak.. Why is the length of the span returned as 0??

Comment: @Sushanth-- huh?  It works for me...   The output should be `0 1`

Comment: You have closed the span element with a </div>, that can be the issue. however it works for me on FF16.

Comment: yup it does  After changing it to Dom Ready instead of load.. Also the span has no closing tag in the fiddle..  Thanks

Comment: my mistake - the plugin code was correct but the HTML markup wasn't.  It did work as is on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to throw an exception if more than one element is returned without use [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to check it. Another aproach would be to use `$("selector").first()` to work only with the first element.

Comment: my problem is - elements with non-unique names, causing exection flow problems. anyway I 've got the answer.